# How to display math formulas that exist in the python file?

Tags: python, math, formula, vscode-extensions

I have downloaded my programming assignment from the web that includes mathematical formulas for the functions used in the assignment.
However, when I open the Jupiter Notebook file in the VS code, the math formulas used in the code show up like this:

```
$$ h(z) = \frac{1}{1+\exp^{-z}}$$
```

I wish to know whether there is a way to visualize the actual formula.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Paste the formula (without the dollar signs) here:  https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter appears to be using something called LaTeX, a way of writing math as normal characters (characters you can type on a keyboard and such). VSCode is displaying the raw text, and doesn't natively support displaying it in the math format. However, [this VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) adds something pretty close. Among other things, it lets you see a preview of the math.

Alternately, you could open the file or view the text in another software. If you remove the dollar signs (`$$`) bracketing the equations, you can paste it into something like the desmos calculator (screenshot attached).
[image: You can paste the equation into desmos if you remove the dollar signs.]

[Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/) or a LaTeX viewer like [LaTeX Base](https://latexbase.com/d/c7ca200b-6014-4f86-851d-a63823916a86) could also work (again, without the dollar signs).

Comment: Thank you. I know how the formulas look like since I can see them on web page where I downloaded the assignment. I know that I can also use something like Overleaf to display them. I just wanted the formulas to show up in a similar way on my code script on the VSCode. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to visualize anything on the code line using the extension you provided either. If that extension can actually do the job, I would appreciate hearing more about the specific ways.

Comment: @JulietaMatevosyan Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that it can display the formulas in-line. The two features in this vein are that if you hover over the LaTeX code, it displays a little pop up showing what the math looks like, and you can build the document into a pdf and view it that way.